# Events and observers; what is being cached?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, full-page-cache, magento-2.0.7, geoip

I am using Cloudflare to [retrieve the Geo IP of a user](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-CloudFlare-IP-Geolocation-do-).

When using this in `pub/index.php` it always works and I am able to set the correct store view based on the header Cloudflare is passing.

However, this doesn't seem good practice (and it is ignored in my repository too). So that's why I'm trying to do it correctly via this observer:

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="elephant_cfparent_controller_redirect" instance="Elephant\CFParent\Model\ObserverGeoIP" />
</event>
```

However, this is being cached, resulting in an incorrect store view for a user in another country. Is anyone aware on how I can do this without cache? Or am I using the wrong event name for example?

Cache is normal Magento FPC (no Varnish) and I'm on Magento 2.0.7.

Answer (score 2):

You can try another event `controller_front_send_response_before`

Answer (score 1):

Use around plugin on `\Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface::dispatch` method and do redirect without call dispatch method.

Comment: Cheers. That should work too. I found out that the event works though, but my code was wrong. D'oh! But I'll leave this question and the answer for if someone ever wonders how this works.

Comment: @ToomyK i am getting same issue as my controller_action_predispatch event get cached and my code does not execute for second time

Comment: @TommyK, were you able to fix the issue? I am using Varnish and my observer is not being called when the cached content is loaded.